# adobe flex popup

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, adobe

I need to close the popup(adobe flex), non modal window if I click on the parent page of the popup. I have to do the out of focus check and then do some validation before close the popup. So what I was thinking that is there any inbuilt focus check event or do we need to create custom event for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your popup you need to listen for mouse up event on the popup itself, and the stage. On the popup if you catch a mouse up event, stop it from getting to the stage. Then, if you receive a mouse up event on the stage you will know that it was outside of the popup and can close the popup.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="400" height="300" creationComplete="onCreationComplete()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

            private function onCreationComplete():void {
                //listen for MouseUp events on the popup, and the stage
                this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, handleMouseUp);
                stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, handleStageMouseUp);
            }

            private function handleMouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void {
                //catch any MouseUp events on the popup, 
                //and prevent them from getting to the stage
                e.stopPropagation(); //don't let this event get to the stage
            }

            private function handleStageMouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void {
                //if the stage fires a MouseUp event, the mouse event 
                //came from outside of the popup, so we can close it
                closePopup();
            }

            private function validate():Boolean {
                //add your validate code here
                return true;
            }

            private function closePopup():void {
                if ( validate() ) {
                    //clean up event listeners, and close popup
                    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, handleStageMouseUp);
                    PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:Canvas>
```

Comment: So that appears to be the convoluted way.. I think you can also just add mouseDownOutside="handleMouseDownOutside(event)" to your popup...